# Prometheus templating in Grafana with label_values - dynamic row and panel repeat

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-templating

Let’s imagine I have a metric called `calories` and two labels called `type` and `name`. `type` says whether we have fruit or vegetable, `name` is a name of the fruit or vegetable e.g. `carrot`, `onion`, `banana`, `orange`, `apple`. What I would like to do is to create a single stat panel that would be repeated in rows in the following way (of course - refreshed dynamically on dashboard load):

`row 1`: **vegetables** with panels for `carrot` and `onion`
`row 2`: **fruits** with panels for `banana`, `orange`, `apple`

My attempt so far is two vars on the dashboard level:
`$types = label_values(type)`.
`$names = label_values(calories{type=~"$types"}, name)`

and I am repeating rows for types and repeating panels for names however unfortunately I am getting all the names (both fruits and veggies) in both rows.

First of all - is this achievable what I am trying to do?
If so - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!